# Remove Elements from an Unordered Map Fulfilling a Predicate

Tags: c++, unordered-map, remove-if

I want to remove elements (histogram bins) from an `std::unordered_map` (histogram) that fulfills a predictate (histogram bins having zero count) given as a lambda expression as follows

```
std::remove_if(begin(m_map), end(m_map), [](const Bin & bin) { return bin.second == 0; });
```

but GCC-4.6.1 complains as follows

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:156:2: error: assignment of read-only member ‘std::pair<const unsigned char, unsigned char>::first’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h: In member function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const unsigned char, _T2 = long unsigned int, std::pair<_T1, _T2> = std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:1149:13:   instantiated from ‘_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = std::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int>, false, false>, _Predicate = pnw::histogram<V, C, H>::pack() [with V = std::vector<unsigned char>, C = long unsigned int, H = std::unordered_map<unsigned char, long unsigned int, std::hash<unsigned char>, std::equal_to<unsigned char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int> > >]::<lambda(const Bin&)>]’
tests/../histogram.hpp:68:13:   instantiated from ‘void pnw::histogram<V, C, H>::pack() [with V = std::vector<unsigned char>, C = long unsigned int, H = std::unordered_map<unsigned char, long unsigned int, std::hash<unsigned char>, std::equal_to<unsigned char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int> > >]’
tests/../histogram.hpp:85:13:   instantiated from ‘void pnw::histogram<V, C, H>::normalize(uint) [with V = std::vector<unsigned char>, C = long unsigned int, H = std::unordered_map<unsigned char, long unsigned int, std::hash<unsigned char>, std::equal_to<unsigned char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int> > >, uint = unsigned int]’
tests/../histogram.hpp:121:51:   instantiated from ‘H& pnw::histogram<V, C, H>::add(It, It) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char> >, V = std::vector<unsigned char>, C = long unsigned int, H = std::unordered_map<unsigned char, long unsigned int, std::hash<unsigned char>, std::equal_to<unsigned char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int> > >]’
tests/../histogram.hpp:129:55:   instantiated from ‘H& pnw::histogram<V, C, H>::add(const V&) [with V = std::vector<unsigned char>, C = long unsigned int, H = std::unordered_map<unsigned char, long unsigned int, std::hash<unsigned char>, std::equal_to<unsigned char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int> > >]’
tests/../histogram.hpp:57:60:   instantiated from ‘pnw::histogram<V, C, H>::histogram(const V&, pnw::histogram<V, C, H>::TYPE_t) [with V = std::vector<unsigned char>, C = long unsigned int, H = std::unordered_map<unsigned char, long unsigned int, std::hash<unsigned char>, std::equal_to<unsigned char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int> > >]’
tests/t_histogram.cpp:38:61:   instantiated from ‘void test_dense_histogram() [with T = unsigned char, C = long unsigned int]’
tests/t_histogram.cpp:64:5:   instantiated from ‘void test_histograms() [with C = long unsigned int]’
tests/t_histogram.cpp:200:29:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:156:2: error: assignment of read-only member ‘std::pair<const unsigned char, long unsigned int>::first’
make: *** [tests/t_histogram.o] Error 1
```

Isn't `std::remove_if` applicable to `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: I fell into this trap too, but now thinking about it std::remove (that moves elements to the end of the container) couldn't work with an associativity container. "the end of the container" doesn't really have meaning any more.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The answer is no (you can't use `remove_if` on associative containers). You need to do a simple loop; the `erase(iterator)` member now returns the next valid iterator - so your loop becomes:

```
for(auto it = begin(m_map); it != end(m_map);)
{
  if (it->second == 0)
  {
    it = m_map.erase(it); // previously this was something like m_map.erase(it++);
  }
  else
    ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is [a proposal of Uniform Container Erasure](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4161.htm) by Stephan T. Lavavej:

```
template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A, class Predicate>
void erase_if(unordered_map<K, T, H, P, A>& c, Predicate pred);
```

i.e.

```
std::erase_if(m_map, [](const Bin& bin) { return bin.second == 0; });
```

Unfortunately it didn't make it C++17.  I suppose this is tied to the adoption of the Ranges TS.

Answer (score 0):

Since c++20, it is possible to use `erase_if` on `unordered_map`.
It will return the number of removed elements.

From the [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase_if):

> std::erase_if (std::unordered_map)
> Erases all elements that satisfy the predicate pred from the container.

In your specific use case (remove all the elements where the second is 0) it would look like:

```
const auto count = std::erase_if(m_map, [](const auto& item) {
    auto const& [key, value] = item;
    return (value == 0);
});
```